# Highcharts: How to add HTML inside of chart area

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, highcharts

Is it possible to add custom HTML (e.g. div) inside of chart area (inside of border;  [Highcharts Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer) does not seem to offer this option)? If yes how would one go about doing this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Renderer is to render elements on SVG/VML. If you want to add HTML tags, add them the same way as is done in Highcharts - position:absolute and set left/top values to put this inside container.

Comment: @PawełFus: Could yo put your comments as the answer please so I can accept.  Much appreciated for help (the answer was so simple).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:**

In the latests versions (v4 at least) in [Renderer API](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer) methods `useHTML` argument was added, for example [`renderer.text(str, x, y, useHTML)`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text) - which will render elements as HTML and position them correctly. Of course simple shapes (`rect`, `path` etc.) are always rendered in SVG/VML.

Extra note: For `HTML` elements, to see them on exported chart, don't forget to set [`exporting.allowHTML`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.allowHTML).

**Old answer:**

Renderer is to render elements on SVG/VML. If you want to add HTML tags, add them the same way as is done in Highcharts - position:absolute and set left/top values to put this inside container.

Comment: Content added this way will not be exported if you use the chart export feature. This may or may not be what you want. If you want it to be exported, then go with Rahul Gupta's answer.

Comment: Good point! In old version of Renderer we could add only SVG/VML elements (not HTML - which is the main point of this question). I don't remember the exact version, but `useHTML` option was added to renderer to some API methods, for example `renderer.text(str, x, y [, useHTML])`, [API](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text).

Answer (score 16):

You will have to use **[Highcharts Renderer API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Renderer)**.

You can refer this [JSFIDDLE working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/HW7Rm/)

it works like:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
....
.....
......
}, function(chart) { // on complete

    chart.renderer.text('This text is <span style="color: red">styled</span> and <a href="http://example.com">linked</a>', 150, 80)
        .css({
            color: '#4572A7',
            fontSize: '16px'
        })
        .add();

});
```

Comment: Was not aware of the renderer before i got here and for me it worked, cause i just needed to add a text link to the graph.

Comment: is it possible to update position for the text like pull it down for 400px by css for it has to be in the text function?

Answer (score 0):

you can refer in this website .
http://pmsipilot.github.io/jquery-highchartTable-plugin/#demo

Hope it will help.